# Collapsing Sparse dataframe in R based on Group By

Tags: r, dplyr, sparse-matrix, plyr, summarize

I have a df that looks like this:

```
Name Var0 Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4
A 0.1 NA NA NA NA
A NA 0.3 NA NA NA
A NA NA 0.4 NA NA
A NA NA NA 0.7 NA
A NA NA NA NA 0.9
B 0.2 NA NA NA NA
B NA 0.5 NA NA NA
B NA NA 0.8 NA NA
B NA NA NA 0.1 NA
B NA NA NA NA 0.3
```

It's essentially a sparse matrix that is grouped by the first column "Name". How can I collapse the rows so that there is only one row per Name? I've tried multiple solutions, including groupby and summarize functions, but can't find a good way to collapse the matrix.

Output I want:

```
 Name Var0 Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4
 A 0.1 0.3 0.4 0.7 0.9
 B 0.2 0.5 0.8 0.1 0.3
```

Comment: For the example you've provided, you could do `data.frame(Name=unique(dat$Name), sapply(dat[-1], na.omit))` in base R.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it

```
df %>% group_by(Name) %>% summarise_all(funs(na.omit(.)[1]))
```